# Corollary 1.17 in Montgomery & Vaughan's Multiplicative Number Theory

Tags: proof-explanation, riemann-zeta, estimation

The following is from "Multiplicative number theory I: Classical theory" by Hugh L. Montgomery, Robert C. Vaughan:

[image]

The proof is very much ambiguous to me. For example:

1- The claim $\int_1^x u^{-\sigma} du = (x^{1- \sigma} -1)/(1- \sigma) < x^{1- \sigma}/(1- \sigma)$ is true for any $ \sigma$. Why the book says it is valid for $0 \le \sigma \le 1 - 1/ \log x$?

2- Why for $\sigma \ge 1 + 1/ \log x$ the integral is $< \int_1^{\infty} u^{- \sigma} du$?

3- I cannot derive (1.29), i.e. where the coefficient $(x^{1- \sigma} + 1)$ comes from?

Comment: [Please do not use images to convey critical information not otherwise present in your post](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/34123/742).

Comment: The proof uses different estimates depending on $\sigma$ and then combines those to get (1.29) (which is probably not the best estimation you can do). 1- the claim is false for $\sigma=1$; also that would be a very bad estimation for $\sigma$ close to $1$. 2- that is true for all $\sigma$ since the integrand is positive